# JButton can't be disabled properly

Tags: java, swing

```
//Click Event for convertBtn
        convertBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //Disable convertBtn temporarily
                convertBtn.setEnabled(false);

                //If amountBox is empty or has an invalid value
                if(!amountBox.getText().matches("^[0-9]{0,10}(\\.[0-9]{1,5})?$") || amountBox.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    amountBox.requestFocusInWindow();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please Enter a valid amount.\nEx: 1234567890.12345", "Invalid Amount", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    convertBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    return;
                }

                //Fetch the exchange rate and place it inside the resLabel.
                //The code connect to a server to fetch the data with the help of a thread.
                //Also Thread.join() is used in the code to wait for the result.
                ExchangeRate er = new ExchangeRate(currencies[fromCombo.getSelectedIndex()], currencies[toCombo.getSelectedIndex()], amountBox.getText());
                resLabel.setText(er.getExhangeRate());

                //Re-enable convertBtn
                convertBtn.setEnabled(true);

            }

        });
```

When the event is triggered the program should disable the button while some processes are executed and after the processes are over the last thing the program should do is to re-enable the button.

Unfortunatly what actually happens is that the the button will not be disabled during the execution of the processes. And when I had removed the last line which is supposed to re-enable the button I noticed that the first line which is intented to disable the button at the beginning is actually executed after the processes are over!!

Which means both convertBtn.setEnabled(false); and convertBtn.setEnabled(true); seem to be executed after the other processes are over!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing uses a single thread for all its event dispatching.  This also includes paint events.

Basically in your code, the `ActionEvent` is delivered to your `actionPerformed` method, you do some work (disable/enable the button) and then the method returns.  Only at this point is it possible for Swing to process any new events (including repaint events).

This means that until the `actionPerformed` exists, nothing on the UI will be updated.

See [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details.

So, what's the solution?

Well, the most common solution would be to use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

This will allow you to perform work off the Event Dispatching Thread, but which also provides convenient functionality for interacting with the UI, like updating a progress bar.

You can also listen to the worker to see when it's done and reset the state of the button

Comment: @shb2789 as an addition to this answer, I recommend [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)